# Azure mobile service and Azure storage integration

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage

We use Azure Mobile Services with Javascript (Node.js) back-end. The front-end is HTML/Javascript and runs as Azure Web App. We want to use Azure blob storage to store files (uploaded from front-end). I searched for a working example implementing this scenario, but I can't find it. There are examples with .NET back-end or Android/Windows Phone front-end. As a workaround it's possible to post the file to mobile service and do the storage from there, but the mobile service api body has a 1MB limit. I know I have to use a Shared Access Signature (SAS), but I don't know how to implement that. Generating the url from mobile service works. But it's not accepted when I use it in the client.

This guide is not working anymore: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: if your frond-end has code on server side, you can easily use azure storage SDK to generate SAS and talk to Azure storage https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node (i assume you are running nodejs)

Comment: Hi Xiaomin, server side is Azure Mobile Services with JavaScript (node.js). It's possible to generate SAS there with the Azure storage SDK, but it doesn't work when I use this SAS on the frontend (plain JavaScript). Authorization errors.

Comment: if you are trying to access azure stroage from your client side javascript code directly, you will hit cross origin issue. you will need to config your storage account i believe. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535601.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yes CORS is also an issue, but even when I use chrome with --disable-web-security I get authentication errors (Authorization header signature)

Comment: Did you configure your storage account? to enable CORS, you need to have CORS rules in your acccount. please refer to the link i post above

Comment: I have CORS rules implemented, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: when you say "doesn`t work". do you see a different error? will be good if there is some network trace. there must be something wrong on your code i think.  see another discussion here where it discuss about how to access Queue storage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691018/how-to-access-azure-storage-queue-by-javascript

Answer (score 1):

As usually, custom APIs on mobile services are used in handling logic workflows or event triggers. So Azure mobile service limit the body size of custom APIs requests for better performance. To implement upload files from clients to Azure Storage, we recommend to leverage SAS URIs.

And lots samples use the backend project to generate the SAS URI and return back to  front-end.We can leverage Azure Node.js SDK in Mobile service custom APIs scripts to generate SAS URI.

Here is the code snippet:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var azure = require('azure');
    var qs = require('querystring');
    var accountName = { accountName };
    var accountKey = { accountKey };
    var host = accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey, host);

    var startDate = new Date();
    var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
    expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 30);
    startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() - 30);

    var sharedAccessPolicy = {
      AccessPolicy: {
        Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
        Start: startDate,
        Expiry: expiryDate
      },
    };
    // you can custom send container name and blob name via http get request
    /** e.g. var containerName = request.query.container, 
                 blobName = request.query.blob

        client side use invokeApi method, e.g.
        client.invokeApi('getSAS',{
            method:'GET',
            parameters:{container:'mycontainer',blob:'myblob'}
        })
    **/
    var blobSAS = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature('mycontainer', 'myblob', sharedAccessPolicy);
    var sasQueryString = qs.stringify(blobSAS.queryString);
    var sasUri = blobSAS.baseUrl + blobSAS.path;
    response.send(sasUri+"?"+sasQueryString);
};
```

You can refer to [Upload images to Azure Storage from an Android device](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-upload-data-blob-storage/#update-the-registered-insert-script-in-the-management-portal) and [Work with a JavaScript backend mobile service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/#custom-api) for reference.

Furthermore, for a deep understanding of generating SAS URI, you can refer to [Constructing a Service SAS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn140255.aspx) and [Shared Access Signatures, Part 1: Understanding the SAS Model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/)

Additionally, here is a similar example built in this architecture, [Upload files to Microsoft Azure Storage from JavaScript](https://www.returngis.net/en/2014/09/upload-files-to-microsoft-azure-storage-from-javascript/)

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your reply! I didn't have time to check this. I will do that asap and come back to you.